# Есть ли какие-то сервисы для хранения своих шаблонов кода?

Tags: шаблоны, веб-служба

Стал программировать относительно недавно, и первая из глобальных проблем, с которой столкнулся — кучи новых фич по ходу работы получаются (необычные методы реализации задач, профитные кнопочки-тумблеры-шапки и так далее), а хранить их негде. На своём компьютере не вариант, не удобно.

Отсюда и вопрос: есть ли какие-то сервисы для хранения своих шаблонов кода?

Comment: предпочитаю хранить локально, так как сеть бывает недоступной

Comment: - http://gist.github.com,  - http://plnkr.co,  - http://gostash.it/ru,  - https://jsbin.com/, - http://codepen.io/

Comment: @stack-it прочитал комментарий, ненадолго задумался, почему ссылка на сервис stack.it ведёт на stackoverflow. Потом понял. :)

Answer (score 2):

Gist используют для этого. А для приватных проектов - VSTS. Кстати, для гиста есть расширение под саблайм. Нажал пару кнопок и загрузил нужный. Мы так на экзамене списывали